# How is an Annexure different from an Appendix?

Tags: meaning, differences, abbreviations

I am reviewing a rather large(~150 page) design document and I feel that some sections are more descriptive and overloaded with jargon. *However*, modifying those sections seem to dilute the point being emphasized.

Thus, I have decided to suggest the original author to abbreviate/modify some of the technical jargon and move them to a different section. The author will be required to

- expand the jargon, and
- explain the pertinent business context.

However, I can't decide between an [*Annexure* and an *Appendix*](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Annex_vs_Appendix). In my case, which one do I suggest to the original author?

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you intended the addendum to be capable of standing alone, or to be a work containing additional information that can be referred to? Assuming the latter, I would use "appendix."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In summary, an **annex** and an **appendix** are both forms of addendums to a main document. An **appendix** contains data that cannot be placed in the main document and has references in the original copy or file. An **annex**, on the other hand, is usually a standalone document that offers additional information than contained in the main document.

Looking at definitions, we get:

**annex**

> *verb*
>
> add as an extra or subordinate part, especially to a document

Annex is a term used more commonly in business models and ideas.

**appendix**

> *noun*
>
> a section or table of subsidiary matter at the end of a book or document

Appendix is a term more commonly used in the research field.

An appendix cannot be submitted without the main copy. The aim of an appendix is to add greater details, visuals and examples for better understanding of the main copy. An annex, however, is different from an appendix in that it can be considered without the main text. It cannot be added to the main text but still has importance as regards the original copy.

Also, do note that appendices are usually written by original authors whereas annexes can be written by another party.

In this case, through the context given, I would assume you want the author to dissect the jargon and the business context in the design document, and since these information contains data that has references to the original copy and can hardly be used as a standalone document, I would suggest **appendix**.

Comment: This definition is still ambiguous in my view - `data that cannot be placed in the main document` does not seem exclusively different to `additional information than contained in the main document`.  While just leaves `and has references` for annex.  But presumably both an annex and an appendix _can_ both be referenced in the main document. So I'm still inclear what the difference is!

Also, I believe annex in this context is a noun not a verb.